# How to Change the Console.Writeline(text) output text font size in a Console App

Tags: c#, console-application

As an example, we have text such as "Hello World!". I use Console.Writeline("HelloWorld!") and "HelloWorld!" prints in a console app. Is there any way to print "HelloWorld!" larger in a console app?

Comment: Consoles do not support that.

Comment: you want a programmatic solution? if not just goto preferences and change the font size......  :::)))))

Answer (score 7):

Text colors and background colors can be changed quite easily.
Look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color. 
Font, is a bit 'undercover', though. Look here: [possible to get/set console font size in c# .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554536/possible-to-get-set-console-font-size-in-c-sharp-net)
Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

Im on Windows 10: run your program and when the console window comes up, right click on the console window (on the top portion where the file name is) and select Properties. You can change your fonts and window size there. Close and rerun program and BINGO...all done.

Note: The font changes you make are not permanent. You may have to make them again depending on how you use the console.

Comment: This suggestion has already been made in a comment to the original question.

Answer (score -3):

You have to make a right-click on the line title of an output window. Select properties and change the font, size or background color.