# Are non-rectangular console characters possible?

Tags: c#, console

I'm working on console application to draw pictures via the character background color. There is also a small amount of text output. The problem is that the console's character are rectangles, not squares, so the pictures come out stretched vertically. Is there any way to change the default character shape or font in console?

Comment: Why don't you think to strech your picture instead of changing console chars...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554536/possible-to-get-set-console-font-size-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: As L.B. suggests: stretch the picture horizontally before you 'paint' its pixels!