# SetCurrentConsoleFontEx isn't working for long font names

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, console, pinvoke

I can't get this to work for font names that are 16 characters or longer, but the console itself obviously doesn't have this limitation. Does anyone know a programmatic way to set the font that will work with the built-in "Lucida Sans Typewriter" or the open source "Fira Code Retina"?

## This following code works:

I have copied PInvoke code from various places, particularly [the PowerShell console host](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleControl.cs), and the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.7.2#unicode-support-for-the-console)

Note that the relevant docs for [CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-font-infoex) and [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) do not talk about this, and the struct defines the font face as a WCHAR field of size 32...

Also note what's not a limitation, but *is* a restriction from the console dialog, is that the font has to have True Type outlines, and must be genuinely fixed width.  Using this API you can chose variable width fonts like "Times New Roman" ...

However, in the API, it has to have *less than* 16 characters in the name --    which is a restriction the console itself doesn't have, and *may* be a bug in the API and not my code below

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    private const int FixedWidthTrueType = 54;
    private const int StandardOutputHandle = -11;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, bool MaximumWindow, ref FontInfo ConsoleCurrentFontEx);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, bool MaximumWindow, ref FontInfo ConsoleCurrentFontEx);


    private static readonly IntPtr ConsoleOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(StandardOutputHandle);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct FontInfo
    {
        internal int cbSize;
        internal int FontIndex;
        internal short FontWidth;
        public short FontSize;
        public int FontFamily;
        public int FontWeight;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.wc, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string FontName;
    }

    public static FontInfo[] SetCurrentFont(string font, short fontSize = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Set Current Font: " + font);

        FontInfo before = new FontInfo
        {
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>()
        };

        if (GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref before))
        {

            FontInfo set = new FontInfo
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>(),
                FontIndex = 0,
                FontFamily = FixedWidthTrueType,
                FontName = font,
                FontWeight = 400,
                FontSize = fontSize > 0 ? fontSize : before.FontSize
            };

            // Get some settings from current font.
            if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref set))
            {
                var ex = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine("Set error " + ex);
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ex);
            }

            FontInfo after = new FontInfo
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>()
            };
            GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref after);

            return new[] { before, set, after };
        }
        else
        {
            var er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("Get error " + er);
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(er);
        }
    }
}
```

You can play with it in a PowerShell window by using `Add-Type` with that code, and then doing something like this:

```
[ConsoleHelper]::SetCurrentFont("Consolas", 16)
[ConsoleHelper]::SetCurrentFont("Lucida Console", 12)
```

Then, use your console "Properties" dialog and manually switch to `Lucida Sans Typewriter` ... and try just changing the font size, specifying the same font name:

```
[ConsoleHelper]::SetCurrentFont("Lucida Sans Typewriter", 12)
```

And you'll get output like this (showing the three settings: before, what we tried, and what we got):

```
Set Current Font: Lucida Sans Typewriter

FontSize FontFamily FontWeight FontName
-------- ---------- ---------- --------
      14         54        400 Lucida Sans Typeʈ
      12         54        400 Lucida Sans Typewriter
      12         54        400 Courier New
```

You see that weird character on the end of the "before" value? That's happens whenever the font is longer than 16 characters (I'm getting garbage data because of a problem in the API or the marshalling).

The actual console font name is obviously not length limited, but perhaps it's not possible to use a font with a name that's 16 characters or longer?

For what it's worth, I discovered this problem with [Fira Code Retina](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), a font that has exactly 16 characters in the name -- and I have a little bit more code than what's above in [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/af95aeece9c3e49815a266bcd8594f1f) if you care to experiment...

Comment: I mean, the memory allocation is probably only 16 bytes if you're getting garbage data.  I'm surprised an exception or SEGFAULT isn't being thrown.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought @TheIncorrigible1, but when I tried shortening it in the struct declaration, the API threw invalid data exceptions. I think an internal API uses shorter names, and breaks it.

Comment: It's worth noting that I have multiple examples of fonts (like Lucida, or Fira Code) where one family (e.g. "Lucida Console" or "Fira Code Light") works, but another fails (e.g. "Lucida Sans Typewriter" or "Fira Code Retina" or "Fira Code Medium"). This seems to confirm it's *just* the name length.

Comment: I also recently discovered that NerdFonts.com truncates the font name on the "Windows Compatible" .ttf files they ship -- so e.g. every one of the 10 variations of "Fura Code" has a "Windows Compatible" version where the TrueType Font Name is just "FuraCode NF"

Comment: Thanks for reporting Joel. Any chance you could transfer this to a Console bug report [here](https://githib.com/microsoft/console/issues) - we're tracking this via internal bug 19017834.

Comment: Yep. I could @RichTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/258#issuecomment-433143842) in the Console API. It's fixed as of Windows 10 (insider) build 18267.

Prior to that release, there wasn't a way around it -- except to use fonts with shorter names, or use the actual window properties panel to set it.

The original post code works now ...