# Get current console font info

Tags: c#, .net, image, console-application, viewer

I am writing an Image Viewer in C# .NET for the console. My problem is that the console font characters are not squares. And I'm treating them as pixels, this stretches the images when drawn on screen.

I want to somehow read the font information about the currently used font, with `width`, `height` etc properties...

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6554568/5698805), but it seems like it just lists all the currently available fonts.

I played around with this code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct ConsoleFont
{
        public uint Index;
        public short SizeX, SizeY;
}

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern bool GetConsoleFontInfo(IntPtr hOutput, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bMaximize, uint count, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] ConsoleFont[] fonts);
```

This did not return the specific font used in the current console window.

I still want to use something like the `ConsoleFont` struct for storing font properties. But the `GetConsoleFontInfo(...)` does not do this as said...

Please if someone knows how to do this, tell me :)

Comment: Avoid undocumented functions.  [Use this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetConsoleFontSize.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution was to implement these lines:

```
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public class CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
        {
            private int cbSize;
            public CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX()
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX));
            }
            public int FontIndex;
            public COORD dwFontSize;
            public int FontFamily;
            public int FontWeight;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string FaceName;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COORD
        {
            public short X;
            public short Y;

            public COORD(short X, short Y)
            {
                this.X = X;
                this.Y = Y;
            }
        };

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        extern static bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, bool bMaximumWindow, [In, Out] CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX lpConsoleCurrentFont);
```

And then just read the current console font information like:

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX currentFont = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false, currentFont);

// currentFont does now contain all the information about font size, width and height etc...
```