# Instead of currency symbol I get a question mark into the Command Prompt

Tags: c#, linq

I use Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, C# and .NET 4.5.

My problem is the output of the line below :

```
 Console.WriteLine("Car`s value: {0:C} ", myNewCar.determineMarketValue());
```

`myNewCar.determineMarketValue()` returns a double.

How can I fix this problem?

My output is this:
[image: qmarkc#]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lesson15SimpleClasses
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myNewCar = new Car();
            myNewCar.Make = "Oldsmobile";
            myNewCar.Model = "Cutlas Supreme";
            myNewCar.Year = 1986;
            myNewCar.Color = "Silver";

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; 

                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",
                myNewCar.Make,
                myNewCar.Model,
                myNewCar.Color);


            Console.WriteLine("Car`s value: {0:C} ", myNewCar.determineMarketValue());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    class Car
    {

        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public double determineMarketValue()
        {
            double carValue = 100.0;

            if (this.Year > 1990)
                carValue = 10000.0;
            else
                carValue = 2000.0;

            return (carValue);
        }

    }


}
```

I added my code ..so simple yet doent work :(

Update: Code updated to use `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;` 
and also my currency and console setting are shown below:
[image]

The problem as you can see is that even though i updated my code to use unicode changed my cmd settings to use Lucida Console font when i execute the program from VS the font remains the same Raster fonts option.

LAST EDIT:Here is how to change the console font used by Visual Studio console fast and simple.Now currency appears correctly in my program : [Control console font & layout used by C# .NET console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589173/control-console-font-layout-used-by-c-sharp-net-console-application)

Comment: This will be an encoding issue... Make sure you are not using ASCII and checkout Unicode / UTF etc.

Comment: Can you show what you get and also the value of `myNewCar.determineMarketValue()`?

Comment: Also: What is your current culture? e.g. what are the language settings in Start->System Settings? What are the currency settings there?

Comment: @strax you will get different output based on culture. for more information look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where can i check my encoding setting for the project?

Comment: I checked my culture settings they have the euro as as currency

Comment: Seems to be the same issue in Chrome's dev console. Would that be the same issue or a different one altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by design.

.NET console application outputs text using some predefined system font (usually Lucida Console, but it can be Consolas or other similar font).

That font not necessary has symbol for your currency, so that symbol can be displayed incorrectly. See [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/lucida_console/blockview.htm?block=currency_symbols) for supported currencies symbols in Lucida Console.

You can't easily fix it in console application just because it is not so easy to change font used for displaying text in console (it is possible with some WinAPI calls, I suppose).

Comment: The problem as you can see is that even though i updated my code to use unicode changed my cmd settings to use Lucida Console font when i execute the program from VS the font remains the same Raster fonts option.
Please check my update.

Comment: As you can see currency symbol is supported by  Lucida Console

Comment: @strax ooh.... you haven't specified exactly that you currency symbol is euro in original question. Yes, Lucida Console can output this symbol (of course, using `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`). But key point of my answer was something like "you can't be sure what your program being executed on computer other that yours will use correct font having all symbols you need to display console text". As I said - there is no easy way to change console font programmatically. Have a look at one of the approaches: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/

Comment: What you said was correct and here is the answer on how to change the console font used by Visual Studio console fast and simple.Now currency appears correctly in my program : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589173/control-console-font-layout-used-by-c-sharp-net-console-application See my LAST EDIT

Answer (score 23):

Add

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

before writing output.

You should also ensure the console font is TrueType.

Comment: My font options  are only 3 Lucida Console, Consolas and Raster Fonts

Comment: @strax Then you only have to try three times, you are lucky! :)

Comment: The problem as you can see is that even though i updated my code to use unicode changed my cmd settings to use Lucida Console font when i execute the program from VS the font remains the same Raster fonts option.
Please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
using System.Text;
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
```

Then you can use your keyboard € symbol... it works for me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

**This was not enough for me**, the question mark was replaced by even more unreadable characters. The font being used by my console program did not support the euro-sign.

Lucida Console and Consolas both do.

To make sure that the correct font is started by default:

- Start your console program (using visual studio)
- Select the control box in the upper left corner
- In the drop down menu select Defaults
- On tab fonts select Lucida Console and a size you are comfortable with

Now the next time you start your console program in visual studio the euro sign is displayed correctly.